# How to restore missing Google App Engine Application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

A google project was deleted and restored after about a week. In the image below there is a stopped app engine. Neither testing nor default exists anymore. Clicking on either throws a "Requested entity was not found" error in the browser console. Why do I see these as existing in the asset inventory and are searchable, but they do not seem to exists as actual App Engine applications and services? Are app engine applications deleted in as little as a week even when the project is restored?

[image]

Comment: Start the instance. What do the App Engine logs show?

Comment: I see no GAE instance or app at all within the GAE UI, so there isn't anything to start. Checking the logs, I can see that the app was sent a shutdown signal when the project was deleted. I can see more logs through GAE over the next couple of days being sent but they error out presumably because the app is no longer running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the app engine service status is "user disabled " , it's one of the reasons you can not use the previous available app engine or create a new app engine. Also try to disable that service and create a new app engine again.

Also check if Datastore is enabled and in-use for the project.
App Engine cannot be deployed in a project that already has Datastore in-use. You can try creating a new App Engine application first and then create the Datastore in the same region.

If you enabled the app engine service and re-created a new app engine , and are still facing the same issue , then the only workaround would be to create a new project. Then you can create an App Engine in the same region you used before.

Also you need to consider that restoration takes more time to function as everything.

Also as @John Hanley suggested try to restart the instance and please check on the app engine logs.

Also take a look at this [Documentation -1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project) and [Documentation -2](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects:%7E:text=Some%20services%20have%20delays%20in%20restoring%20and%20you%20might%20need%20to%20wait%20some%20time%20for%20services%20to%20be%20restored).

If the above steps doesn’t help, you may consider contacting [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) as it may requires project inspection.

Comment: Datastore gives me "The Google App Engine app linked with this database is disabled. Please unlink this Datastore database for continued access." However, I don't see any existing GAE app at all, so there is no service for me to restart.

Comment: As per the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) there might be a chance that all the resources might not be fully recoverable even if you restore the project within the 30-day period. You may contact [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) to confirm whether all the resources are restored or not and also to know what is causing the issue.